# how to display sub menu under the respective main menu

Tags: routes

I want to display main menu in custom menu block and display all sub menu below the main menu block on clicking the respective main menu. Iam able to display main menu but not able to display respective sub menus below the clicked main menu. Please help

I would like to give a reference if my reqiurement is not clear. The submenu created in the site http://stmarksumc.com/node/159 is what I am looking for.Can anyone please   suggest me any solution to the issue Drupal 7?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the module [menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block). This module allows you to display child items of a certain parent item of a menu.